Why did I get "incompatible pointer to integer ..."warning?
I just tried to use pointer to get the address of the first of an array and read the elements one by one. I used the pointer to not accompy a big part of the memory. Here is the variables:
unsigned char *RawAudio;
extern const unsigned char bootup[];

And here I got the warning:
*RawAudio = bootup;

And here is the warning I got:

Why? How to figure it out?

*RawAudio is a char, that cannot hold a pointer. Did you mean RawAudio without the star?

What are you trying to achieve? What should RawAudio contain after *RawAudio = bootup;?

@BoP Why " without the star"? I want to store the address of it.

But *RawAudio = stores the address in the memory that RawAudio points to, not in the pointer itself.

@Jabberwocky RawAudio is supposed to store the address of the first element of the bootup. Then I will read element by element of the bootup. That's just to minimize usage of the ram memory.

You really want unsigned char *RawAudio = bootup;

Why do you think this will minimize RAM usage? There's no difference between using RawAudio[i] and bootup[i]. They both access the memory of the bootup array.

@Barmar Yes. thats what I want.

@Barmar But I heared that's what I get If I use a pointer.

You heard wrong or misunderstood. Actually, there's a difference. When you use bootup[i] the compiler knows the address of bootup, so it doesn't need to indirect through the pointer. It's a tiny bit more efficient.

You only need the pointer if you need to be able to change which array it points to dynamically.


Two issues.  You assign pointer to unsigned char (*RawAudio = bootup;), but I think is a typo. You need to RawAudio = bootup;.
When you RawAudio = bootup; the RawAudio pointer will reference a const object. Modifying a const object invokes Undefined Behaviour. The compiler will emit a warning - you may want to silence it (if by using explicit cast)


EDIT
Silencing the warning does non make code UB free.

So he probably also wants const unsigned char *Rawaudio; instead of unsigned char *Rawaudio; rather than an explicit cast like RawAudio = (unsigned char*)bootup;

RawAudio = (unsigned char*)bootup; ... *RawAudio = something will invoke undefined behavior as well.

@Lundin what did I write in p2? I do not understand why you comment on something which is already in the answer.

@gulpr You mention that the compiler might be "silenced" with an explicit cast, but the code has undefined behavior still, hence the comment. Casting wouldn't turn the code well-defined, it would just hide the bug "under the carpet".

@Lundin where did I write that silencing warnings makes code UB free?  I wrote that it is UB!. I amended the answer for you

"you may want to silence it (if by using explicit cast)" is a recommendation to the OP so it could be misunderstood, is all. No need to start hyperventilating just because someone leaves a comment - comments are not important, answers are.
